# 'float' object is not iterable in python

Tags: python

I have the following function:

```
def cambiar_tamano(size):
if 'M' in size:
    x = size[:-1]
    x = float(x)*1000000
    return(x)
elif 'k' == size[-1:]:
    x = size[:-1]
    x = float(x)*1000
    return(x)
else:
    return None
```

which aims to convert sizes. For example, convert "25M" to a numerical
value. 
But when I try to implement it, I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Edit: This is the dataframe structure

[image: Dataframe]

The call to the function:

```
data_store["Size"] = data_store["Size"].map(cambiar_tamano)
```

Being "data_store" the name of the dataframe, and the trace:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-abbd67041e83> in <module>()
      7 #print(Size)
      8 
----> 9 data_store["Size"] = data_store["Size"].map(cambiar_tamano)
     10 data_store.Size.fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace = True)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   2996         """
   2997         new_values = super(Series, self)._map_values(
-> 2998             arg, na_action=na_action)
   2999         return self._constructor(new_values,
   3000                                  index=self.index).__finalize__(self)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
   1002 
   1003         # mapper is a function
-> 1004         new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
   1005 
   1006         return new_values

pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-34-72b73c9e233b> in cambiar_tamano(size)
      1 def cambiar_tamano(size):
----> 2     if 'M' in size:
      3         x = size[:-1]
      4         x = float(x)*1000000
      5         return(x)

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

Thanks!

Comment: worked for me, once i fixed the indentation

Comment: When you are applying this, some of your `size`s are floats and you are using methods not available to floats, for instance `'M' in 17.0`, or more likley `'M' in np.NaN`.

Comment: 1. Please fix your indentation. 2. Please show the whole stack trace. The stack trace should show which line in the code is throwing the error.

Comment: Please fix indentation, show how you're calling the function, show what data you're calling the function with, and the stacktrace of the error. It works fine for me if I fix the indentation and call it with the strings `'25M'` or `'25k'`, so your issue is likely due to what data you're passing to the function, which we can't see obviously.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Look at `data_store[pd.to_numeric(data_store["Size"], errors='coerce').notnull()]`. This should show you that you have some rows where the values of `Size` are either `np.NaN` or small numbers like `975`. You're going to need a case to just return the value if they are floats.

Answer (score 0):

The error simply says "TypeError: **'float' object is not iterable**"

Try passing a collection, probably as a string eg. `"25M"` and then typecast to required data type as needed post extraction etc.

Refer:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TypeError